# Why is my database reverting back to old information?

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, h2

I am using H2 embedded databases for my software application. When the sale dialog is pulled up, it allows a user to enter a customer name, and then to begin inserting item numbers. As item numbers are added and the 'Enter' key is pressed, the quantity on hand (in the database) is reduced by 1. If the item is removed from the table, the quantity is added back to the database. This is to provide the user with a real-time update when they have run out of a specific item, and it lets them know that if they truly do have this item on hand, they will need to make sure it is updated in the inventory editor.

Also, if the sale is cancelled, all of the items are added back to the inventory.

I tried running two instances of my application at the same time, one to begin entering information for a sale, and another to check the quantity of the item in the inventory editor. It was keeping a real-time update, as it should. However, when I clicked "Complete Sale", the quantity reverted back to the old quantity.

Here is my code for my `CompleteSaleButton`:

```
private void CompleteSaleButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    String sChangeDue = ChangeDueTextField.getText();
    double dChangeDue = Double.parseDouble(sChangeDue);

    if(dChangeDue < 0) {
        int confirmation = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "The user has not paid the full amount. Proceed?", "Incomplete Payment", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (confirmation == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            ProceedWithSale();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please prompt the user to complete the payment, and then proceed.", "Proceed With Payment", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    } else {
        ProceedWithSale();
    }
}
```

And here is my code for `ProceedWithSale()`:

```
public void ProceedWithSale() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    //Get tax rate
    String TaxRate = "";

    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./RetailApplicationDatabase;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");

        String sql;
        Statement stmt;

        sql = "SELECT TaxRate FROM SETTINGS WHERE OnOff = 'ON'";
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (results.next()) {
            TaxRate = results.getString("TaxRate");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        JTextArea ErrorMessage = new JTextArea("Error: " + ex, 6, 40);
        ErrorMessage.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ErrorMessage.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane ErrorPane = new JScrollPane(ErrorMessage, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        ErrorPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ErrorPane, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    double TaxRateAmount = Double.parseDouble(TaxRate);

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) SaleItemTable.getModel();
    int RowCount = model.getRowCount();

    String TicketNo;
    String CustomerID;
    String InventoryNo;
    String Description;
    String Cost;
    String Retail;
    String IndividualSubTotal;
    String IndividualTax = "";
    String IndividualTotal = "";
    String SaleSubTotal;
    String SaleTax;
    String SaleTotal;

    for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++) {
        TicketNo = TicketNoNumberLabel.getText();
        CustomerID = CustomerIDLabel.getText().substring(13);

        InventoryNo = String.valueOf(SaleItemTable.getValueAt(i, 0));

        Description = String.valueOf(SaleItemTable.getValueAt(i, 1));

        Cost = String.valueOf(SaleItemTable.getValueAt(i, 2));

        Retail = String.valueOf(SaleItemTable.getValueAt(i, 3));

        IndividualSubTotal = String.valueOf(SaleItemTable.getValueAt(i, 3));
        double dIndividualSubTotal = Double.parseDouble(IndividualSubTotal);
        double dIndividualTax = dIndividualSubTotal * TaxRateAmount;

        String sIndividualTax = df.format(dIndividualTax);
        double dIndividualTotal = dIndividualSubTotal + dIndividualTax;

        String sIndividualTotal = df.format(dIndividualTotal);

        SaleSubTotal = SubTotalAmountLabel.getText();
        SaleTax = TaxAmountLabel.getText();
        SaleTotal = AmountDueAmountLabel.getText();

        java.util.Date javaDate = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date SQLTransactionDate = new java.sql.Date(javaDate.getTime());

        DatabaseRecords SaveSale = new DatabaseRecords();
        try {
            SaveSale.SaveSale(TicketNo, CustomerID, InventoryNo, Description, Cost, Retail, IndividualSubTotal,
                    sIndividualTax, sIndividualTotal, SaleSubTotal, SaleTax, SaleTotal, SQLTransactionDate);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            JTextArea ErrorMessage = new JTextArea("Error: " + ex, 6, 40);
            ErrorMessage.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ErrorMessage.setLineWrap(true);
            JScrollPane ErrorPane = new JScrollPane(ErrorMessage, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            ErrorPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ErrorPane, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The sale has been saved.", "Sale Saved", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    CustomerSearchTextField.setEnabled(false);
    InventoryNoTextField.setEnabled(false);
    DescriptionTextField.setEnabled(false);
    CostTextField.setEnabled(false);
    RetailTextField.setEnabled(false);
    AddButton.setEnabled(false);
    RemoveSelectedItemButton.setEnabled(false);
    SaleItemTable.setEnabled(false);
    CompleteSaleButton.setEnabled(false);
    TenderedTextField.setEnabled(false);
    CancelButton.setText("Finish");

    DatabaseRecords IncreaseSaleTicketNumber = new DatabaseRecords();
    try {
        IncreaseSaleTicketNumber.IncreaseSaleTicketNoNumbering(TicketNoNumberLabel.getText());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JTextArea ErrorMessage = new JTextArea("Error: " + ex, 6, 40);
        ErrorMessage.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ErrorMessage.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane ErrorPane = new JScrollPane(ErrorMessage, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        ErrorPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ErrorPane, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JTextArea ErrorMessage = new JTextArea("Error: " + ex, 6, 40);
        ErrorMessage.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ErrorMessage.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane ErrorPane = new JScrollPane(ErrorMessage, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        ErrorPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ErrorPane, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    SaleReceipt Receipt = new SaleReceipt();
    Receipt.InitializeReceipt(TicketNoNumberLabel.getText());
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing the information in my database to revert back to the original quantity.

EDIT: 02/02/2015 (8:33 AM MST) -

`AddQuantityToInventory`:

```
public void AddQuantityToInventory(String InventoryNo) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./RetailApplicationDatabase;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);

    String sql;
    Statement stmt;
    PreparedStatement prepare;

    sql = "SELECT Quantity FROM Inventory WHERE InventoryNo = '" + InventoryNo + "';";
    stmt = connection.createStatement();

    ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    String currentQuantity = "0";

    while(results.next()) {
        currentQuantity = results.getString("Quantity");
    }

    int newQuantity = Integer.parseInt(currentQuantity) + 1;

    sql = "UPDATE Inventory SET Quantity = '" + newQuantity + "' WHERE InventoryNo = '" + InventoryNo + "';";
    prepare = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    prepare.execute();
}
```

`RemoveQuantityFromInventory`:

```
public void RemoveQuantityFromInventory(String InventoryNo) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./RetailApplicationDatabase;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);

    String sql;
    Statement stmt;
    PreparedStatement prepare;

    sql = "SELECT Quantity FROM Inventory WHERE InventoryNo = '" + InventoryNo + "';";
    stmt = connection.createStatement();

    ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    String currentQuantity = "0";

    while(results.next()) {
        currentQuantity = results.getString("Quantity");
    }

    int newQuantity = Integer.parseInt(currentQuantity) - 1;

    sql = "UPDATE Inventory SET Quantity = '" + newQuantity + "' WHERE InventoryNo = '" + InventoryNo + "';";
    prepare = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    prepare.execute();
}
```

EDIT: 02/02/2015 (8:40 AM MST) - Here is the code for when the InventoryNoTextField focus is lost. I don't think this is the problem, because the information does not revert back when I 'Tab' to a different field. But, I thought it might be valuable information, so I added it.

`InventoryNoTextFieldFocusLost`:

```
private void InventoryNoTextFieldFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                               
    String InventoryNo = InventoryNoTextField.getText();

    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./RetailApplicationDatabase;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE");

        String sql;
        Statement stmt;

        sql = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE InventoryNo = '" + InventoryNo + "';";
        stmt = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(results.next()) {
            DescriptionTextField.setText(results.getString("Description"));
            CostTextField.setText(results.getString("Cost"));
            RetailTextField.setText(results.getString("Retail"));
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        JTextArea ErrorMessage = new JTextArea("Error: " + ex, 6, 40);
        ErrorMessage.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ErrorMessage.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane ErrorPane = new JScrollPane(ErrorMessage, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        ErrorPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ErrorPane, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

EDIT: 02/02/2015 (12:15 PM) - I added the `commit` statements to both database record methods for updating the quantity.

Comment: Where do you actually update the data in your database? I only see a select statement in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I have a separate class called DatabaseRecords that I use to update most of my database records. I will add them to the initial post. I only run the AddQuantityToInventory when I remove items from the table or when the sale is cancelled, and I only run RemoveQuantityFromInventory when the items are added to the table.

Comment: I don't understand it, the quantity is being properly stored, until the sale is saved. Once the sale is saved, it is reverted back to the old quantity. I'm not sure why it's doing this...

Comment: I see no commit statements anywhere.

Comment: I have never had to commit in any other changes. I have heard of the commit statement, but I have never used it. Why would this situation be any different, just out of curiosity?

Comment: Also, I just added `sql = "COMMIT";`, `stmt = connection.createStatement()`, and `stmt.execute(sql)`, and I also tried making the last line `stmt.executeUpdate(sql)`, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: As @Gimby mentioned, you probably don't actually commit the changes. You should either add connection.setAutoCommit(true) after your Connection connection = DriverManager..., or add connection.commit(); after your prepare.execute() statement.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I was trying to `COMMIT` via SQL code, when I should be committing via Java code. I will try that when I get a chance. I will post an update when I try it. Thank you for the help. Should I use `COMMIT` after EVERY change that I make, or just in this case? Also, please post your response as an answer, so that I can accept it (provided this solution works). Thank you.

Comment: I added `connection.commit();` after my `prepare.execute();` statement, and I also tried to add `connection.setAutoCommit(true);` after my `connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...);` statement, and neither worked. I even tried to add `connection.close();` at the end of my `RemoveQuantityFromInventory` and `AddQuantityToInventory` methods, and it still didn't work properly. Any other suggestions?

Comment: try doing something like "int i = prepare.executeUpdate()" and print "i", as well as newQuantity. This should give you an idea if any entry is actually update.

Comment: @OferLando - I know the update is actually being performed, because I ran two instances of the application. In one of them, I added the items to the table in the sale dialog. Then, I checked the quantity in the inventory editor in the other instance of the application, and it was 1 less. I added another one in the sale dialog, and it was 1 less again. Then, it displayed my message stating that there are no more in inventory, but it still allows the user to add it to the sale (in case the inventory quantity was just wrong), and it was set to -1. (I started with a quantity of 2.)

Comment: Once I save the sale, the quantity is reverted back to the quantity that it was at before I completed the sale. Everything else works okay. One would think that the completion of my sale has something to do with it, and that I am running the `AddQuantityToInventory` method, but I have checked, and I'm not.

Comment: I think it's funny... I got a downvote on the question, but it's extremely detailed and I haven't yet gotten a solution that works. So, how exactly is this question worthy of a downvote?...

Comment: The downvote was added minutes after you posted the question, when it wasn't-as-detailed... I'll upvote the question, "just to get you straight" :-)

Comment: Are you aware of what `jdbc:h2:./RetailApplicationDatabase` means? It means the database file is stored in the current working directory. If you start your application from another working directory, you will have two databases. I suggest to use an absolute path instead, for example `jdbc:h2:/data/db/RetailApplicationDatabase`, or relative to the current user home directory, as in `jdbc:h2:~/db/RetailApplicationDatabase`

Comment: @ThomasMueller, I have had nothing but problems with absolute paths in the past, and I want people to be able to run the application on any workstation and be able to share the database over the network.

Comment: @RyanShukis ok what about relative to the current user home directory, instead of relative to the current working directory? Even thought I don't understand what problem you have with absolute paths. And local file names don't usually over the network.

Comment: @ThomasMueller - Right. This application can be shared over the network when it is stored in a path relative to the current working directory. Plus, it's more work than necessary to gather the username on the user's computer, in order to create the path.

Comment: @ThomasMueller, I really don't see what the location of the database has to do with my issue anyways. I am running one instance of the application, and everything is being saved up until I complete a sale. Then, the quantity in the inventory database reverts back to the old quantity on hand.

Comment: @RyanShukis for two reasons: one is, you might end up with two separate databases instead of just one. The second reason is other people reading this question. Using relative path is not recommended.

Comment: @ThomasMueller, I don't see how I would end up with two databases. AUTO_SERVER=TRUE should allow multiple users to access the information at the same time without any damage being done. Also, when an absolute path is used, I wouldn't be able to share the application over a network. (At least not in a way that the client would understand, anyways.)

Comment: @RyanShukis You can't access remote databases with a local file name. I suggest to re-read the [documentation](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url).

Comment: @ThomasMueller, the application can be shared over the network by simply sharing the folder that it is installed in. This is something that would be fairly simple for a user to do, and it would allow many systems to run the application, all within one location.

Comment: @RyanShukis OK, this should work.

Comment: @ThomasMueller, what should work?

Comment: @RyanShukis this should work: "the application can be shared over the network by simply sharing the folder that it is installed in".

Comment: @ThomasMueller - By "this should work", you mean using a relative path, correct?

Comment: @RyanShukis yes, relative path and remote access. If you know what you do then that's fine, but my experience so far was that many people don't know what they do... That's why I consider relative paths dangerous.

Comment: @ThomasMueller - Ah, gotcha. Yeah, I use the AUTO_SERVER=TRUE function to allow multiple connections, and I use a relative path, which allows the entire application directory to be shared over a network. Then, users can just create a shortcut to the application on the network, and they can run multiple instances at one time.